# Did Robert E. Howard write anything other than Conan the Barbarian that’s not a collection of short stories?

Tags: conan, robert-e-howard

I’ve been reading *Kull: Exile of Atlantis* and *Conan the Barbarian*. I love them, but I am wondering if there’s a larger non-short story book by Robert E. Howard?

Comment: I don't know that this is a list question. It seems more of a factual "Did he write a non-Conan non-short story book?" question, which has a simple answer, as seen below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Howard wrote only one full-length novel that was published in his lifetime, which he titled *[The Hour of the Dragon](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/42243/42243-h/42243-h.htm)*.  Many printings rename it *Conan the Conqueror*.  It was serialized in *Weird Tales* in 1935–1936, starting with the [December 1935](https://archive.org/details/Weird_Tales_v26n06_1935-12_sas_-783-784_ifcibc/mode/2up) issue.  It is not a fix-up, per se, but is very episodic.

Besides this, Howard did, however, write a number of intermediate-length genre stories, about Conan and otherwise.  The longest non-novel works published by Howard appear to be the [planetary romance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_romance) "[Almuric](https://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks07/0701111.txt)" (which was labeled as a "novel" when it was serialized in *[Weird Tales](https://archive.org/details/Weird_Tales_v33n05_1939-05_AT-sas/mode/2up)*, but is really more of novella length), the Conan story "[The People of the Black Circle](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0600941h.html)" (which takes place in India and Afghanistan and is one of Howard's most popular works, although I don't personally care for it), and the modern story "[Skull-Face](https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/howardre-skullface/howardre-skullface-00-h.html)" (which has some interesting fantasy elements, but, as you might expect from a Howard story set in present-day London, has a lot of racist ideas).

Comment: I guess you don't accept the posthumous novel [*Almuric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almuric) as authentic Robert E. Howard?

Comment: @user14111 Posthumously published does not necessarily mean posthumously rewritten; I'll go by the attribution given by major sources, so I've included that in my answer.

Comment: @user14111 Is a fix-up a novel?

Comment: @user14111 I have updated my answer with more information about the intermediate length works.

Comment: @DavidW [Just wanted to tag you too].

Comment: @Buzz If *Almuric* isn't a novel at 157 pp. (despite ISFDb, Wikipedia and other sources, like the SF-encyclopedia, saying it is) then neither can be Norton's *Huon of the Horn* (128pp), Dick's *The Cosmic Puppets* (127pp) or Piper's *Planet for Texans* (125pp), and many many others.

Comment: @Spencer Yes, a fix-up novel is a novel. They were very common in the Golden Age.

Answer (score 3):

According to a [search by author and title type](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=author_canonical&O_1=exact&TERM_1=Robert+E.+Howard&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=NOVEL&USE_3=title_language&O_3=exact&TERM_3=English&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title) on ISFDb (you may need to be logged in to run it), there are 7 novels credited to Howard, however 2 of those are non-SF, and 3 were completed by others after his death.

**The two novels written by and credited solely to Howard are [*Conan the Conqueror*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6504) (1950) reprinted in 1977 as *The Hour of the Dragon* and [*Almuric*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9635) (1964) which is not related to any of his major series.**

The 3 novels that were completed by others after his death, for which credit is shared are:

- [*The Treasure of Tranicos*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?17493) (1980) by L. Sprague de Camp and Robert E. Howard
- [*Conan: Flame Knife*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?27855) (1981) by L. Sprague de Camp and Robert E. Howard
- [*King Conan and the Stygian Queen: Beyond the Black River*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2514965) (2016) by Robert E. Howard and Jess Eden Thornton

The two non-SF novels are:

- [*A Gent from Bear Creek*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?720565) (1937), a humorous western
- [*Post Oaks & Sand Roughs*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6586) (1990), a [roman à clef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_%C3%A0_clef).

Note that Wikipedia records [*The People of the Black Circle*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63633) and [*Skull-Face*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?91768) as novels, but ISFDb has them both recorded as novellas.

Comment: Note that *Almuric* has a 1964 date, but it was serialized in 1939.

Comment: *A Gent from Bear Creek* is really a short story collection that was published posthumously as a novel.

Comment: @Buzz Quoth ISFDb: "*Fix-up novel* of 13 related stories, all but three were first published in Action Stories from March 1934 to August 1935. The *stories were slightly revised by Howard*, and are presented as chapters of the novel" (emphasis mine); so they may have originally been short stories but they tweaked into a single narrative and published as a novel.  Wikipedia and the REHoward foundation say the same.